# How to keep running a flutter app in a physical device?

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm developing an iOS app with flutter and I've succeeded into running it in my physical iPhone device. As soon as I disconnect my iPhone from my MacOS (unplugging it), the app stop to work (in visual studio code "exited" appear). My question is: is It possible to keep the app working on my physical device without the necessity of being connected to my MacOS?

I'm sorry if the question is trivial but I'm kind of new in flutter and I wasn't able to find similar question.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't keep the app running in debug mode on devices running iOS 14+. You can either run the `profile` or the `release` version using

```
flutter run --profile
flutter run --release
```

Comment: which is the difference between profile and release?

Comment: You can read more about it [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes)